# Java multi threading - threads are not being called before semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, semaphore

I am trying to create something that looks like this:
I have a class that opens an HTTP connections: `ConnectionContext`.
This class has a semaphore named `connections` that allows to open `maxConnections`.
It looks something like this:

```
public ConnectionContext(..., int maxConnections, ...) {
    ...
    this.connections = new Semaphore(maxConnections);

    public void acquireOne() throws InterruptedException {
        connections.acquire(1);
    }

    public void acquireAllAndClose() throws Exception {
        this.connections.acquire(maxConnections);
        closeHTTPConnection();
    }

    public void releaseOne() {
        this.connections.rlease(1);
    }
}
```

I have another class called `HTTPConnector`, which contains this `ConnectionContext`:

```
public class HTTPConnector {
    protected final ConnectionContext connectionContext;

    public HttpWriter(..., int maxConnections, ...) {
        this.connectionContext = new ConnectionContext(..., maxConnections, ...);
        ...
    }

    public void execute() {
        ...
        connectionContext.acquireOne();
        connectionContext.process();
        ...
        connectionContext.releaseOne();
    }

    protected void close() throws Exception {
        connectionContext.acquireAllAndClose();
    }
}
```

So this is more or less the structure of my program and now for the problem:
If I open several connections with multi threading, I call once to the `HTTPConnector` and run `HTTPConnector.execute()` several times and each time get a permit from the semaphore, and after all the jobs are done I am calling `HTTPConnector.close()` to close the connection.

but, some of the times, `HTTPConnector.close()` is being called before I call all the `HTTPConnector.execute()`, and then the connection is closed before all the jobs are done.

my question is, how to make sure that `HTTPConnector.close()` is being called only after making sure that there are no `HTTPConnector.execute()` on the way?

Comment: You need to make sure that when you run your threads, you execute the [.join](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-join) method. This method waits for the thread to finish it's execution.

Comment: @tomerpacific so only after the `.join` I should call the `close` function? how can I implement it then? I'm not sure that the `join` is fit in here, I thought maybe something like `executorPool` or something but I'm not sure

Comment: @StackerSapper - where in your code do you release the retain count from the semaphore? What is the use for the semaphore? The join method waits for the thread to finish it's execution, which from your description, is what you want.

Comment: @tomerpacific the `join` won't help, because a thread that call `close` can still start, before a thread that should have call `execute` was called, and then still the connection will be closed because it didn't know that an `execute` was suppose to come.

Comment: @Holger at the end of `execute` I release one connection. I edited my code.

Comment: When an `execute()` operation does acquire and release, there could be an infinite number of `execute()` calls one after another. So "making sure that there are no `HTTPConnector.execute()` on the way" is impossible. Unless you have a stressable definition of "on the way".

Comment: @Holger ok so I guess something is wrong in the login I wrote it, because indeed I can have 10 threads for example run at the same time, and the thread that calls `close` being executed before 8 others, then only 2 connections will be open, because this thread closed the connection. How can I implement it differently then?

Comment: You have implemented a mechanism which allows **n** *at the same time*, which happens to limit to **n** *total* if you call `close()` in the middle of the first **n** operations, at least sometimes. You have to make up your mind, do you want to have a total limit of **n** connections or do you want to allow more than **n** connections if `close()` has not been called.

Comment: @Holger I want to allow **n** at total, though I don't want to `close` the **n** operations in the middle, before I make sure that all operations are indeed over.

Comment: You can use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to allow the close operation to wait for the completion. Or use a [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) or [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) which even allows to specify the close operation so that the last completed operation will immediately close the connection.